# Allow sorting on only a specific element using jQuery sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I need to allow sorting on a specific element using jQuery sortable.Please check code below.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("tbody").sortable();
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="grid">
                <td>AB</td>
                <td>ab@ab.com</td>
                <td><img src="icon_info.gif" border="0" alt="Info" title="Info" class="icon"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="grid">
                <td>CD</td>
                <td>cd@cd.com</td> 
                <td><img src="icon_info.gif" border="0" alt="Info" title="Info" class="icon"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="grid">
                <td>EF</td>
                <td>ef@ef.com</td>
                <td><img src="icon_info.gif" border="0" alt="Info" title="Info" class="icon"></td>
            </tr>  
        </tbody>    
    </table>​
</body>
```

In this code I need to allow sorting only on action column not on name and email column. Please suggest if we can do this.

Answer (score 1):

Ans is:

```
first way
      $(function() {
           $("tbody").sortable({
             handle: ".icon"
           });
         });

   second way
 $(function() {
    $("tbody").sortable({
        handle: ".action"
      });
});
```

initialize your handle sortable parameter with `.class` or `#id`. I chose your image `.icon` class.

Comment: As you can see in https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/ta6yw9gv/, it doesn't work for `td`s that aren't in same `tr`.

Comment: @AliSoltani it is ok

Comment: Please see a fiddle like my fiddle that others can see your solution.

Comment: @AliSoltani ha ha according to problem my both ans is correct way i go for your fiddle

Comment: Ramkishan needs to sort only one `td` (`action`) not a row. As I see in your fiddle, the row is changed not a `td`!